# ¿Es "ueko" una palabra real?

Tags: etimología, historia, palabras-raras, dle, animales

En la entrada [**rebeco**](https://dle.rae.es/rebeco) del DLE actual, en la sección relativa a la etimología, se indica:

> Del ant. **ueko**, este del lat. tardío *hybĭcum*, y este del lat. *ibex, -ĭcis*, infl. por el ant. *reves[s]o* 'arisco, indómito'.

Lo mismo aparece recogido en la [edición de 2001](https://www.rae.es/drae2001/rebeco) del DLE.

Si no lo entiendo mal, esto indica que la palabra latina *ibex* dió lugar a la palabra latina tardía *hybĭcum* que a su vez dió lugar a la palabra antigua **ueko**, la cual, influida por la palabra antigua *reves[s]o*, dió lugar a la actual y moderna palabra **rebeco**.

La dificultad que encuentro es que no encuentro **ueko** en ningún sitio: ni en el DLE, ni en el NTLLE, ni en el CORDE. La grafía **ueko** con **k** no parece española, pero no se indica que la palabra corresponda a otro idioma, o que sea una forma supuesta o hipotética, o una transcripción fonética.

¿Es **ueko** una errata del DLE, arrastrada desde al menos 2001? ¿Es o era **ueko** una palabra real, en español u otro idioma? ¿O lo he entendido todo mal?

Comment: ¿ No tiene un exemplo del uso?

Comment: No sé nada al respecto, pero me pregunto si fue una palabra que se figuraba en alguna inscripción celtohispánica, ya que se me hace que usaban ellos la k, amén del hecho de que *hybĭcum* viene del latín tardío, según el DLE.

Comment: Puede que la "u" se lea como "v" en este caso, y se lea "veko", que haría más plausible el paso a "rebeco".

Answer (score 1):

Según Corominas, ese "ueko" sería una voz navarra que aparece de forma aislada en una glosa del siglo XI, aunque Corominas la escribe "ueco", y sería una adaptación del italiano "becco". En todo caso, Corominas rechaza esa etimología y le da más credibilidad a la teoría de que venga de un antiguo "ribiccu" por metátesis de "bicirru", originario del actual "becerro".

Answer (score 1):

## **Sobre la palabra "ueko" y "Rebeco".**

### Voces y documentos

Hybicum, Glosario Turza, año 964.

Ueko, Navarra, 1074.

Documento de 1074, de la Catedral de Pamplona

- Soto uno que dicitur arrusticis Aker Çaltua - Soto uno que es llamado por los campesinos Aker Çaltua
- Nos possumus dicere Saltus ircorum* - Podemos decir 'Bosque de los Machos Cabrios'.

- hircus-i

Interlineada lleva la frase - Nos possumus dicere Soto de ueko - Podemos decir Soto de ueko

- Soto es un terreno poblado de árboles y arbustos, generalmente a la orilla de un río.

Se quiere ver en el paraje Soto de hircus - Soto de ueko" una relación entre ibex, y su variante Hybicum/Ibicum/bicum/ bikum - ueko/veko/beko y una referencia entre los parajes ircus/hircus, Macho Cabrio / Beko - Rebeco.

Documento completo en el Boletín de la Comisión de Monumentos de Navarra, 1927, 1, 55 8-563.
J. M. Lacarra, Vasconia medieval. Historia y filología. San Sebastián, 1957, 24, también recoge el fragmento.

Otras variantes
Robeço, Toledo, 1434.
Rebeço, Guillén de Segovia, 1470.

Desde mi punto de vista sin extenderme mucho diré, que tanto Corominas como el resto de autores que han atendido a la voz yerran al iniciar su discurso desde un planteamiento prerromano, queriendo ver en ibex, ibicis, beiceor, ibicurri los primeros antecedentes y aquellos otros relacionados Hybicum, Ibicum, bicum...

En consideración creo que estos hay que buscarlos, en este caso en antiguas voces árabes y no en el latín o en el vasco. Así estimo que la propia voz "becerro", datada igualmente por Corominas en el año 964, es una adaptación de una vocablo utilizado por los musulmanes para las cabras que a su vez procedería de la antigua zona de Irán y la influencia que ejerció este sobre el Califato de Córdoba, antes de que Abderramán III decidiera, en el 929, proclamarse Califa y supusiera la definitiva ruptura con los califas de Bagdad.

Así del Persa tenemos la palabra "pâdzahr", que en árabe se transforma en "Bezoar", ya que ellos no pronuncian la "P". La cabra de tipo bezoar, es una subespecie de cabra salvaje que puebla las montañas de Turquía, Irán y Afganistán. Esta voz se transformará en suelo hispano en bicurri, bicerra..."Becerro" - Be - zo - ar / Be-ze -rr-o.

Ya sea por distinción, clasificación u otra razón, dado el gran número de especies de cabras silvestres e igualmente la facilidad de confusión con otros animales de procedencia similar pues hasta 1985, dentro de "rebeco" como denominación se incluían otras diez subespecies.

La voz becerro experimenta un cambio de lugar de los sonidos dentro de la misma palabra, así en esta metátesis tenemos Be -ce rr - o / la erre pasa al primer lugar / RR- e - be - c -o.

Compárese todas las voces, y la misma fuerza de sus sonidos/ "Bezoar" - "Be -ce - rra/o" - "Re - be - co". Solo existe una trasmutación de sonidos en una misma palabra.

P.D. "pâdzahr" - son bolas que se van formando ya sean de fibra o pelo y que no pueden pasar al intestino. Para los antiguos tenían propiedades curativas y era utilizado contra venenos, de hecho  "pâdzahr" significa "antidoto".

Diego